# If two random variables have the same PDF/PMF, then does this mean they have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The title says it all. If the above statement is not true, then could you please add an example, would be much appreciated!

Comment: PMF = ? But yes, of course, having the same distribution $\iff$ have the same pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Todd PMF means probability mas function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ and $Y$ both have pdf $f$ then $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(y)dy=F_Y(x)$ and if (integer valued random variables) $X$ and $Y$ have pmf $(p_n)$ then  $F_X(x)=\sum_{n \leq x} p_n=F_Y(x)$.